# Updating a single element in a nested list with official C# MongoDB driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver, nosql

I have a simple game with multiple rounds and I want to update the most recent round:

```
class Game
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public List<Round> Rounds { get; set; }
}

class Round
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
}
```

How can I do the equivalent of `games.Rounds.Last().A = x` using the official MongoDB C# driver?

Edit: Added Round.B. Note that in this case, both A and B may be updated concurrently so I cannot save back the entire document. I only want to update the A field.

Comment: do you want to do this atomically, or are you ok to pull back the document, modify it, and then send in the change?

Comment: I would like to send only the change. Multiple parts of the Round can be edited concurrently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the drivers with LINQ support, then I suppose you could do this:

```
var last = collection.AsQueryable<Game>().Last();
last.A = x;
collection.Save(last);
```

I imagine it wouldn't be as efficient as a hand-coded update statement, but this does functionally mirror your javascript version for the most part.

Edit: Without LINQ, and doing a subset update

```
var query = Query.EQ("_id", MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue.Create(games.Id);
var update = Update.Set("Rounds." + games.Rounds.Length - 1 + ".A", MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue.Create(x));

Collection.Update(query, update);
```

Not so pretty looking, but you can index into an array by the number in Mongo, so you'd miss out on the case where a new Round was added to the game before you update.

Comment: I'm not using LINQ actually. Also, per my edit, I only want to update the A field and not save the entire document since some other fields in Round may be updated concurrently with A.

Comment: Ah, so I need to have each Round have an ObjectId as well?

Comment: Actually, I somehow missed that it was all nested. I'll think about it a bit more.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
var query = Query<Entity>.EQ(e => e.Id, id);
var update = Update<Entity>.Set(e => e.Name, "Harry"); // update modifiers
collection.Update(query, update);
```

I hope you find this useful. Thanks.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Wesley wants to know how to update a nested child element.